# Execute function on image change with carouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

This seems to be pretty basic but i can't find anything on the topic, i tried looking the [Advanced Documentation](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel-advanced) and here but nothing.

I need to execute a callback when the carousel changes the image to do some DOM manipulation. is there a way to do that?

Comment: How embarrassing, you are all right. i tried the fiddle with all the examples and was what i needed. Funny thing is i tried the same exact thing into jsbin and didn't work. i'll give it a shot in there later to see why it didn't work. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#caroufredsel-6").carouFredSel({
responsive  : true,
items       : 3,
width: '100%',
height: 'auto',
  scroll: {
        duration: 1000,
        timeoutDuration: 3000,
  onBefore : function( data ) {
       console.log("Transition");
       //alert("Transition");
  }
}
});

});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/PwCJb/

Answer (score 1):

There is an onAfter Attribute

```
onAfter : function(oldItems, newItems) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `scroll.onAfter` do just that?

```
Function that will be called right after the carousel finished scrolling.
This function receives the same parameter as the onBefore-callback function.
```